# WPF: Evaluate XAML binding beyond top level custom object

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my xaml I declare a custom object which has a property referencing another custom object:

```cs
public class CustomObjectA : FrameworkElement
{
   public CustomObjectB InnerObj
   {
      get { return GetValue(InnerObjProperty); }
      set { SetValue(InnerObjProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerObjProperty = 
                          DependencyProperty.Register("InnerObj",
                                                      typeof(CustomObjectB),
                                                      typeof(CustomObjectA),
                                                      new PropertyMetadata(null));
}

public class CustomObjectB : FrameworkElement
{
   public string Data
   {
      get { return GetValue(DataProperty); }
      set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = 
                          DependencyProperty.Register("Data",
                                                      typeof(string),
                                                      typeof(CustomObjectB),
                                                      new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Now when I declare these objects in my xaml like this the binding doesn't work:

```
<my:CustomObjectA>
   <my:CustomObjectA.InnerObj>
      <my:CustomObjectB Data="{Binding someValue}" />
   </my:CustomObjectA.InnerObj>
</my:CustomObjectA>
```

However when I declare these objects in my xaml like this the binding works:

```
<my:CustomObjectB x:Name="testObj" Data="{Binding someValue}" />

<my:CustomObjectA InnerObj="{Binding ElementName=testObj}" />
```

I'm assuming this is because the system mapping the bindings doesn't look past the top level object.  My question is; is there a way to tell the system to evaluate binding expressions beyond the top level custom object so xaml like option 1 will work?

Comment: I can check this out and if it works I might post an answer - but my initial feeling is that the datacontext is not being passed down to objectB, hence when you have the binding outside of the object it binds properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataContext is not passed down to the InnerObj. I got it to work by updating the DataContext when the InnerObj changes:

```
public class CustomObjectA : FrameworkElement
{
    public CustomObjectB InnerObj
    {
        get { return (CustomObjectB)GetValue(InnerObjProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InnerObjProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerObjProperty =
                           DependencyProperty.Register("InnerObj",
                                                       typeof(CustomObjectB),
                                                       typeof(CustomObjectA),
                                                       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnInnerObjUpdated));

    private static void OnInnerObjUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var local = (CustomObjectA)d;
        var newObj = (CustomObjectB)e.NewValue;

        newObj.DataContext = local.DataContext;
    }
}
```